# Spring-data-mongodb db-factory id does not work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a working copy of mongo-config.xml which uses the default id of db-factory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo id="replicaSetMongo" replica-set="localhost:10901,localhost:10902">
<mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
ssl="false" />
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory
mongo-ref="replicaSetMongo"
dbname="logs"
username="logs_owner"
password="logs_owner" />

<mongo:mapping-converter>
<mongo:custom-converters>
<mongo:converter>
<beanclass="com.utils.mongodb.dao.impl.SspLogsWriteConverter"/>
</mongo:converter>
</mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<beanid="xmlLogTemplate"class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
<constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
<constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
<propertyname="writeConcern">
<util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED"/>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

However we have requirement to connect to 2 different databases on the same mongodb replica-set. Hence I want to define 2 different mongo:db-factory beans. So I made the following change:
(Only the changed beans are shown below)

```
<mongo:db-factory id="xmlDbFactory" 
    mongo-ref="replicaSetMongo"
    dbname="logs"
    username="logs_owner"
    password="logs_owner" />

<beanid="xmlLogTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="xmlDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
    <property name="writeConcern">
    <util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

As soon as I deploy this change, my JBoss starts throwing errors at startup as follows.
Is this a bug in Spring, or am I doing something wrong?

```
15:33:37,507 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexCreationHelper': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoDbFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:615) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoDbFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: can you add the declaration of indexCreationHelper? Are you sure you do not start 2 standalone spring contexts in the same application?

Comment: @Martin, indexCreationHelper gets created by Spring - I do not control its creation. I have only 1 spring context.

Comment: Try to upgrade to spring 3.2.8 if you want to use spring data mongo 1.4 (internal visibility changes between 3.2.7 and 3.2.8).

Comment: Spring version 3.2.8 is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the db-factory, it's the mapping-converter that has an optional argument "db-factory-ref". This argument is internally preset to "mongoDbFactory" to match the default "id" of the db-factory.

So the "id" of the db-factory works, but the "db-factory-ref" of the mongo-conver has to be set accordingly:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="xmlDbFactory" ... />
<mongo:mapping-converter db-factory-ref="xmlDbFactory">
```